# TypeScript: Is it a good practice to use labmdas by default for instance level methods?

Tags: javascript, c#, lambda, typescript, this

I believe [I understand](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) the [difference](http://piotrwalat.net/arrow-function-expressions-in-typescript/) and the impact of using lambdas instead of 'regular' functions in TypeScript classes.
The gist is that lambdas preserve 'this' and they should be used especially if the class method can be 'passed around', reassinged etc, etc.

As someone with C# background, my question is: 
Should I always default and prefer to using lambdas for class methods?
Again, I am expecting most would say 'it depends', but I am asking this in context of best practice, safety, and sane defaults.

For illustrative purposes here is a sample TypeSrcript class and what it transplies to in ES6 and ES5:

```
//
// ...following class in TypeScript:
//
export default class AppConfig {
    private _configFilePath: string;    

    public constructor(configFilePath: string) {
         this._configFilePath = configFilePath;
        // do stuff...
    }

    // getter for private instance field
    public get configFilePath(): string { return this._configFilePath; };   

    // override toString using lambda
    public toString = (): string => {
        return `App Config: (config file: "${this._configFilePath}")`;
    }

    // override toString using 'regular' function 
    // the '2' toString2() at the end is just to make it compile and demo 
    public toString2(): string {
        return `App Config: (config file: "${this._configFilePath}")`;
    }   
}


//
// transpiles to following when targeting ES6:
//
class AppConfig {
    constructor(configFilePath) {
        this.toString = () => {
            return `App Config: (config file: "${this._configFilePath}")`;
        };
        this._configFilePath = configFilePath;
    }

    get configFilePath() { return this._configFilePath; };  

    toString2() {
        return `App Config: (config file: "${this._configFilePath}")`;
    }

}

//
// and transpiles to following when targeting ES5:
//
var AppConfig = (function () {
    function AppConfig(configFilePath) {
        var _this = this;
        this.toString = function () {
            return "App Config: (config file: \"" + _this._configFilePath + "\")";
        };
        this._configFilePath = configFilePath;
   }

    Object.defineProperty(AppConfig.prototype, "configFilePath", {
        get: function () { return this._configFilePath; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    ;   

    AppConfig.prototype.toString2 = function () {
        return "App Config: (config file: \"" + this._configFilePath + "\")";
    }; 
}());
```

Comment: You could improve your question by adding some code that doesn't use a lambda.Then you might see that the function is defined on the prototype, not on each instance, leading to a *faster* instantiation, and to a single function definition instead of one per instance, using *less* memory.

Comment: One problem with lambdas is that you cannot call `super`. I only use a lambda if I know the function will be called as a handler or callback.

Comment: @GameAlchemist `toString2()` is an example of not using lambda...I don't follow you comment....

Comment: @Aaron that is a good point, something I am looking for in an answer ("use lambdas only for callbacks and handlers" (in order to preserve 'this', I presume)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I would only use an arrow function by default for handlers and other callbacks that are expected to be passed around and called from other contexts.

The problem with arrow functions is that they aren't class functions, they are class properties assigned to an anonymous function, so you lose all the class function features: overloading, overriding in subclasses and calling `super`, etc.